# NSMutableArray add the last object only

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, xcode4.5

Let me allow to describe the scenario first. i have an array called "exibitors"
which hold all exibitors information (all array information is parsed from an URL).
Currently it has "107" Fair01 item (fairId = Fair01) & "2" Fair02 item
(fairId = Fair02). Now i want to run a method which return an array.
In this method i will select either Fair01 or Fair02 by checking them with a 
"FairIdPassing" of current ViewController and add the current "FairId"
corresponding data into this method array named "exibitorsWithFairIdComplete".

Here is the method :

```
-(NSMutableArray *) getFairInfoArray:(NSString *)FairIdForThisMethod From:(NSMutableArray*)exibitorsForThisMethod
{
ExibitorInfo *currentExibitors2=[[ExibitorInfo alloc] init];
exibitorsWithFairId = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// "FairIdHolderCount" = how many fairId is there, in the list
int FairIdHolderCount = [exibitorsForThisMethod count];

for (int i=0; i<FairIdHolderCount; i++)
{
    ExibitorInfo *currentExibitors1=[[ExibitorInfo alloc] init];
    currentExibitors1 = [exibitorsForThisMethod objectAtIndex:i];

    if ([currentExibitors1.FairId isEqualToString:FairIdForThisMethod])
    {
        [currentExibitors2 setExibitorName:currentExibitors1.exibitorName];
        [currentExibitors2 setStallLocation:currentExibitors1.stallLocation];
        [currentExibitors2 setExibitorCellBackGround:currentExibitors1.exibitorCellBackGround];
        [currentExibitors2 setCompanyLogoURL:currentExibitors1.companyLogoURL];

     [exibitorsWithFairId addObject:currentExibitors2];   
    }
}
   return exibitorsWithFairId;
}
```

I call the method in "tableView numberOfRowsInSection:", because i want to
show them in a table view. The code is :

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // call the method
    exibitorsWithFairIdComplete = [self getFairInfoArray:FairIdPassing From:exibitors];
    return [self.exibitorsWithFairIdComplete count];
}
```

But the problem is, when i call the method and want to add object to
the array one by one for specific FairId, it only added the last value.
And show its corresponding information.

Example :

```
For Fair02 ----> "exibitors" array contain 2 "Fair02" elements besides 107 "Fair01": 

(in array)
fair id : Fair02, fairName : A, Location: A
fair id : Fair02, fairName : B, Location: B


(fair id : Fair01, fairName : X, Location: X
fair id : Fair01, fairName : Y, Location: Y
fair id : Fair01, fairName : Z, Location: Z
.......
.......
.......
.......
.......
total 107)
```

After calling this method it only print the last "B" related 
information in tow table rows, 
Like :

```
"fair id : Fair02, fairName : B, Location: B"
"fair id : Fair02, fairName : B, Location: B"
```

when i want showing all fairInfo one by one. 
Like :

```
fair id : Fair02, fairName : A, Location: A
fair id : Fair02, fairName : B, Location: B
```

I cannot point out the mistake happen in addingObject to an MutableArray.
Please question me if i am not make this post clearly to you. If any one 
familiar with this problem, please let me know.

Comment: Why did you wrap the prose portions of your question in `<pre>…</pre>` tags?

Comment: For visual comfortable.

Comment: The end result is five blocks of gray that all look like code. How is that visually comfortable?

Comment: You're not doing yourself any favours by gratuitously diverging from the way everyone else formats their questions. I've adjusted it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should make your business :

```
-(NSMutableArray *) getFairInfoArray:(NSString *)FairIdForThisMethod From:(NSMutableArray*)exibitorsForThisMethod {
    NSMutableArray *exibitorsWithFairId = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    // "FairIdHolderCount" = how many fairId is there, in the list
    int FairIdHolderCount = [exibitorsForThisMethod count];

    for (ExibitorInfo *currentExibitors1 in exibitorsForThisMethod) {
        if ([currentExibitors1.FairId isEqualToString:FairIdForThisMethod]) {
           ExibitorInfo *currentExibitors2=[[[ExibitorInfo alloc] init] autorelease];

           [currentExibitors2 setExibitorName:currentExibitors1.exibitorName];
           [currentExibitors2 setStallLocation:currentExibitors1.stallLocation];
           [currentExibitors2 setExibitorCellBackGround:currentExibitors1.exibitorCellBackGround];
           [currentExibitors2 setCompanyLogoURL:currentExibitors1.companyLogoURL];

           [exibitorsWithFairId addObject:currentExibitors2];   
        }
     }

     return exibitorsWithFairId;
 }
```

You were allocating an `ExibitorInfo` object, then throwing it out, accessing the object in the array and then mutating `currentExibitors2` and inserting it in your array. But as the insertion didn't make a copy, you were in fact changing and insering the same object again and again.

Comment: Awesome.....You make my day....:) I got it and it perfectly working. A lot of thanks, @rems4e..... :) :) :), you are the man.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
- (NSMutableArray*) getFairInfoArray: (NSString*) FairIdForThisMethod From: (NSMutableArray*) exibitorsForThisMethod
{
    NSMutableArray* exibitorsWithFairId = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (ExibitorInfo* currentExibitors1 in exibitorsForThisMethod)
    {
        if ([currentExibitors1.FairId isEqualToString: FairIdForThisMethod])
        {
            ExibitorInfo* currentExibitors2 = [[ExibitorInfo alloc] init];
            [currentExibitors2 setExibitorName:currentExibitors1.exibitorName];
            [currentExibitors2 setStallLocation:currentExibitors1.stallLocation];
            [currentExibitors2 setExibitorCellBackGround:currentExibitors1.exibitorCellBackGround];
            [currentExibitors2 setCompanyLogoURL:currentExibitors1.companyLogoURL];

            [exibitorsWithFairId addObject:currentExibitors2];
        }
    }

    return exibitorsWithFairId;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    self.exibitorsWithFairIdComplete = [self getFairInfoArray: FairIdPassing
                                                         From: exibitors];

    return [self.exibitorsWithFairIdComplete count];
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but i already got the solution. Many many thanks for your co operation :) @stosha